# Firebase transaction error

Tags: firebase

I use Firebase to share some status on multiple users on browsers, and use transaction. After some works, I start getting this weird error;

> Uncaught Error: Firebase INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED:tryToSendTransactionForNode_: items in queue should all be run. firebase.js:29

What does this mean? It seems after getting this error, it's not able to update data anymore. And even more weird thing is transaction returns `success=true`.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Firebase JS client. Could you post a code snippet that reproduces this issue please?

Comment: Bump, I'm constantly receiving this error in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

In node.js, you can workaround this by wrapping the call:

```
process.nextTick(function() {
    ref.transaction(function(current) {
        current.something = true
        return current
    })
})
```